# Module.scss cannot style react component

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I do not know why my scss module is not working. Seems like what I put in the scss file is not rendered in the web

Here is my code:

style.module.scss

```
.title {
    color: cornsilk;
}
```

index.js

```
  render() {
    return (
..... Lots of code above
        <div className={styles['title']}>
          hi
        </div>
..... Lots of code below
    );
  }
```

Notice: it is the not file import nor export bug. I checked typo and everything.

Answer (score 0):

if you use one scss file open a _app.js file in root. and add your scss there.

```
import '../styles/Style.scss'


export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

also you can use module.scss
did you import your module page at the top of index.js right? or whatever page name is?  it should work.

Comment: Yep. I import it. But it did not work. I do not know whether this conflict with ant design pre built css style